# Android Libgdx render performance

Tags: android, libgdx

1. I have a `shaperenderer` and some lines in it. In my renderer I have to change the lines alpha. What is a better way to do this instead of `setColor(r, g, b, calculated_alpha)`

   I read that this always create a new object with `new Color()` what is not the best.
2. I have to do some calculation formula. Lets say distance between points. Is it also a good way to calculate those in all render cycle? Better way?
3. I am new in shaders but there is a `lowp`, `mediump`, `highp` precision. I have a Nexus6 and a Samsung g7. I cant see any different by the way on those precisions. What is those for? On a low end device may I have to add a `lowp`?

I just created a simple live wallpaper and my device sometimes a little hot. Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 . That's wrong. Look at the source code if you are in doubt. The method just sets the values for its current Color object and reuses it. No problem to set the color like this.

2 . Depends on where you need it. If the points are static and do not change then you want to calculate the distance once and reuse the result. If the points change position over time then you need to calculate the current distance within the `render()` method.

For calculating Pythagorean Theorem is usually used: http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/distance_formula/index.php

If you use the `Vector2` class to represent your points then you can just do:
float distance = point1.dst(point2);
`dst()` used the PT behind the scenes.

3 . You probably never will see a difference between them with your eyes. It is just how precise floating point numbers in your shader are. mediump is usually used.

Comment: Ok, now I use only one new Color() that is 'global', and use set(r, g, b, a) on it, than add to my shaperenderer via setColor, instead of new Color(..) every time in my render cycle. Thanks